# Finding apk file from terminal so I can upload to google play

Tags: android, ios, xcode, terminal, apportable

I recently created an app on the apple app store, and I want to convert it to android. However, I have absolutely no experience with using terminal, so please forgive me for the "noob" question i am about to ask....

I was able to build a release version of the xcode project, and it's in this directory:

```
/Users/chrisgonzalez/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-release/SuperPowerUP!/SuperPowerUP!-release.apk
```

How do I find this apk file? I tried looking through finder but couldnt find it....

Comment: You should absolutely avoid to use exclamation marks (!) in your file name, this might be the reason why you are not able to find the file since the shell is escaping the char.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go into that directory in the terminal(cd ) and do a open .(dot) It should open up finder in the current directory and you should be able to copy the .apk file to any place you want to.

Answer (score 0):

From the Terminal, type:

`open '/Users/chrisgonzalez/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-release/SuperPowerUP!'`

The single quotes around that directory path will prevent the shell from interpreting the `!` character.  Also single-quoting will help in cases where you have whitespace or non-alphanumeric characters in your path name.

(And as JohnUopini wrote in the comment to your original question, you should probably avoid using non-alphanumeric characters in file/path names).